# Having a hard time with links and centering an image

Tags: html, css

[My HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u77px.png)[My CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmxQc.png)I have two images that are separate links to different web pages that stack on top of each other, so I tried to put display: block; on them, but it didn't work. I am also trying to center the images, but they keep left. My container is centered and I've put margin: 0px auto; on multiple classes and ids to try to make it work, but nothing's happening

Comment: can you please show the markup & css you're referring to?

Comment: … at least the HTML

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to stack and center the 2 `div`s? Or are you trying to center their contents? Also, instead of linking images, you might consider creating a snippet using the button with `<>` in the icon. That will give others the chance to work with the code and to see the results.